# Loading CSS and JS files modularly

Tags: html, css, angularjs

As I continue to add on to my website, for each HTML file i add i need to include

```
    <!-- Source for .css style rules -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Hexdra/assets/css/style.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="/Hexdra/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- JavaScript for using a custom file for resources. -->
<script src="/Hexdra/assets/scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Hexdra/assets/scripts/modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
<script src="/Hexdra/assets/scripts/siteScript.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Apps-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Hexdra/app/tank.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Hexdra/app/form.js"></script>
```

Its not an awful method, and it works every time. I just know there has to be an easier method.

I know theres the  but that doesn't seem like the easiest method.

I know of the js library `require.js` and that's wonderful but if I dont think i can use that for my CSS files.

What I would like is a method of referencing one file, loading one file, and it then has some sort of structure or code that then imports all other required CSS and JS files.

What made me see that i needed this sort of system was to select all the files for `bootstrap` without loading each one like I have loaded my CSS and JS above.

Im sure im missing some key terminology so please help me along with new terms or ideas that Im on the cusp of but haven't found the verbiage to be able to describe yet.

Answer (score 1):

For CSS, there are always `@import` statements.  See here on MDN: [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

Define a single CSS file and use `@import url("some-other.css")` to load all of your CSS files through the singular, "main" CSS file.

For CSS, you could use a CSS preprocessor like LESS or SASS to bundle all your files into a single file through a build step.  The same principle applies to JavaScript as well through some sort of bundler whether it is `r.js` for require.js AMD style application or Browserify for more CommonJS style source files.

Comment: I do use LESS to build my CSS. Would it be wrong to somehow bundle my LESS CSS and Bootstraps CSS?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with referencing a bunch of files in your index, but it is best practice to build your app with something like Gulp before deploying to production. Your gulp process should combine all css and js into respective minified css and js files. There are a lot a performance benefits to doing this. Sorry to be so brief

Comment: Isnt gulp an application that is used for distributing finalized code? I use visual studio and I believe it supports GULP. Ill check it out, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what your back-end language is, but if you are using PHP you can do something like this:

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php
    include 'inc/head.inc.php';
?>
<body>
    <div>All your stuff follows here</div>
    <?php include 'inc/nav.inc.php'; ?>
```

**inc/head.inc.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MyDomain</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="some stuff I do" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="stuff, things, quality" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Hexdra/assets/css/style.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="/Hexdra/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- JavaScript for using a custom file for resources. -->
    <script src="/Hexdra/assets/scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Hexdra/assets/scripts/modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
    <script src="/Hexdra/assets/scripts/siteScript.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Apps-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Hexdra/app/tank.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Hexdra/app/form.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: So far, No backend language. Just HTML, CSS, and ANGULAR. I do have a small JSON file. But its just data not really a back end language like php or asp.net.

Comment: How about when you deploy? Are you building this locally in XAMPP or some such? What environment will you host the site on? Use that back end -- you'll be there anyway. *If you intend to host with a typical hosting company (e.g. GoDaddy / HostGator $50/year package or similar) then you will likely be using a LAMP stack and will have access to PHP. When you install XAMPP or MAMP/WAMP, you have PHP. Have at it.*